# Accessing a closure property of an instance in RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am trying to deep dive into RxSwift and figure out different approaches. I realized some project in Github using similiar code structure as below. I used to think as imperative way but I really wonder what i am missing in Rxswift world.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let observableProperty = PublishSubject<Client.DelegateEvent>()

    struct Client {
        
        static var live: Self { Client(events: { stringInputFromSomeWhere in
            observableProperty.asObservable() // Point 3
        }, setable: {
            { _ = SomeManager().doNothing() }
        }, someId: "cool property")}
        
        
        var events: (String) -> Observable<DelegateEvent>
        var setable: () -> ()
        var someId: String
        
        init(events: @escaping (String) -> Observable<DelegateEvent>,
             setable: @escaping () -> (),
             someId: String
            
        ) {
            self.events = events
            self.setable = setable
            self.someId = someId
        }
    
        public enum DelegateEvent {
            case didUpdate(SpecialLocation)
            case didFail(Error)
        }
        
    }
    
    struct SpecialLocation {
        
    }
    
    class SomeManager {
         func doNothing() {
            print("noThing Worked")
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
        let clearStep = Client.live.someId // Point 1
        let whoAreYou = Client.live // Point 2a 
        whoAreYou.setable() // Point 2b 
        print(whoAreYou.someId)
    
    }
```

---

- Point 1 - Am I accessing a string property of a instance, right ?
- Point 2ab - I think, I am accessing an instance after calling a
  closure,Actually what am I doing here?
- Point 3 - Getting error, **Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type
  'Observable<ViewController.Client.DelegateEvent>**' So How can I fix
  this in a meaningful way ?

Thank you so much for every answer and comment.

Comment: No working project does this because it doesn't work? What project is "similar" to it?

Comment: Also, this *is* imperative the `Subject` gives it away. They are used for converting imperative code into Rx code.

Comment: Lastly, none of your questions have anything to do with RxSwift. They are Swift Language questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Point 1 - Am I accessing a string property of a instance, right ?

Strictly speaking yes, but the instance will be created just for this access and then immediately destroyed. This is rather silly to do IMO.

> Point 2ab - I think, I am accessing an instance after calling a closure,Actually what am I doing here?

Point 2a creates a Client value (not the same one used in Point 1, but it will have the same value.)

Point 2b calls `setable()` on the value. The value object will be destroyed at the end of the viewDidLoad function.

> Point 3 - Getting error, Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type 'Observable<ViewController.Client.DelegateEvent>'

The `Client.live` computed property is a global, you are trying to access an instance variable of a particular `ViewController` from inside that global, but there is no way to define which instance should be accessed.

> So How can I fix this in a meaningful way ?

This question I cannot answer because I don't know what "fixed" means in this context...